# Is there a concise way to define two or more bash aliases for the same expansion?

Tags: bash, command-line, alias, git-bash

Suppose I want to use both `e` and `c` as quick ways to open the current folder in my preferred editor.

Do I need to define my bash aliases like this:

```
alias c="code ."
alias e="code ."
```

Or is there a more concise syntax?  Something like this (which I tried, but it did not work):

```
alias c,e="code ."
```

I've also not found a concise alternative by searching guides, the web, and the [bash alias](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22bash+alias%22+is%3Aquestion) questions here.  Still, it's hard to prove a negative. :-)

---

**Note**: I am specifically using git-bash. I anticpate any answer would apply to bash more generally.

Comment: `bash` does not provide such a shortcut, which really wouldn't be useful for anything except code golf.

Comment: Of possible interest, functions are almost always preferred over aliases, and `zsh` allows you to define a function with multiple names in one command: `c d () { code . "$@" }`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the confirmation that the shortcut doesn't exist. That was indeed my main aim here. One potentially useful scenario: a team uses a shared set of aliases maintained in a repository. Some typists strongly prefer c, others e.  The real life expansion is itself longer and more complicated than the illustration in my question and maintaining it in more than one place within the shared file is inelegant and prone to error. That's a good point about functions.

Comment: I've come to find that aliases (and shell customizations in general) are so personal that's it's rarely worth trying to share them.

Comment: Yeah, regarding the proposed use: define *a* shared function that provides the necessary functionality, and let individual users alias it (if at all) to whatever they want.

Comment: @BenjaminW.  Fair enough.  Experiences vary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
alias {c,e}="code ."
```

...will, after brace expansion, become:

```
alias c="code ." e="code ."
```

...which does what you want.

---

That said, I don't believe this question is on-topic here; aliases are an interactive facility not available by default in scripts, and Stack Overflow is exclusively scoped to *software development*. Writing scripts definitely counts; using your command-line shell, not so much.

Comment: @Charles Duffy.  First, many thanks. :)  Second, as to the topicality aliases are defined in .bash_profile (or the equivalent) which, per the tag description, is a shell ___script___, executed when a bash user logs on.

Comment: @TrevorReid, I'd call that a *configuration file*, even if its contents are code. People who aren't working in or on software development modify `.bash_profile` contents all the time, whereas https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic specifies that an activity must be "unique to software development" to be on-topic. But then, mine is presently the only close vote thus far, so apparently that position isn't widely shared.

Answer (score 0):

While I prefer the accepted answer a workable alternative is to expand the second (third..n) alias(es) into the first, instead of repeating the expansion.

```
alias c="code ."
alias e=c
```